# making the http request context available through dependency injection in global.asax application

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, dependencies, mvp, code-injection

I am trying to understand the usage of making the http request context available through dependency injection in global.asax application start event like this.This is ASP.NET MVP application and the code is

Container.Register(Component.For()

```
            .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest

            .UsingFactoryMethod(() => new HttpRequestWrapper

           (HttpContext.Current.Request)));
```

Can anybody expalin me this code.
what it does?

Comment: generally we register interfaces,classes and assemblies used in our project in register method but what i see here that it takes httpcontext.current.request object means it is controlling the request lifecycle objects also of an ASP.NET application so what is the benefit of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I won't say that this is an absolutely recommended approach, but it helps to resolve `HttpContextBase` dependencies in constructors or properties while building up the object graph. It can be particularly useful when you have classes that depend on `HttpContextBase` so they can unit tested using mocks.